# Expo Stopped ( expo client app is not working )

Tags: react-native, expo

I had been working with react native for few days and I used to run my app in my own android phone through LAN. But recently the expo client app is not supporting. When I open it it shows all the recent project as well as working project. when I click on working once it shows all the normal stuffs like **Dowloading javascript bundles** and in metro bundler also it shows **Building JavaScript bundle: finished in 5380ms**. No problem there. But when it finishes a pop up came and show **Expo stopped**

like this :

[image]

I cleared the cashe and atlast reinstalled expo client app in android device and expo-cli in my system. Still the problem persisting. How to resolve it... :(

Comment: Not sure if related or not, but I know Expo is working on an update, maybe released it already to adjust to googles policy changes...perhaps this is the cause? try updated expo maybe?

Comment: try updated expo means ? I already reinstalled expo client app in android device and expo-cli in my system